# Грамотность кода

Tags: java

Изучаю Java. Написал графическое приложение чисто для себя, для практики. Да, конечно, многое новое узнал, но. Я на 100% уверен, что по большей части код неграмотен и неправилен. И как быть? Как обнаружить свои ошибки?

Попробовал FindBugs, на удивление почти ничего не обнаружил. Парочка переменных, которые, возможно, будут Null. И Dead store переменные.

Comment: Выставьте свой код (один небольшой классик) сюда - посмотрим, покритикуем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Style Guide / Oracle Java Conventions, PMD, CheckStyle, Findbugs, SonarQube

Comment: Воу, неплохо. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

[[@Augoustis](/users/28389/augoustis)](/users/28389/augoustis), изучайте чужой хороший код. Например, [исходники то же Java](http://www.docjar.com/projects/openjdk-7-java.html).

Или [можно посмотреть здесь](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/)

Comment: Да вообще на грепкоде популярные библиотеки почитать полезно.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё совет: старайтесь, чтобы ваш код отражал то, что вы думаете. Чтобы читался естественно, как текст. Чтобы не приходилось писать комментарии по поводу того, что ваш код означает.

Answer (score -1):

Есть ещё вариант - код ревью. Можно поискать товарища поопытнее, который будет ревьюить код и указывать на недостатки. Если такого товарища нет - найдите более менее популярный проект с открытым исходным кодом на github и оформите к нему изменение в виде pull request. В этом случае, вы и ревью получите, и чужой код почитаете.

Answer (score -3):

Предыдущий совет хороший, но есть нюанс. Если пишите приложения или апплеты для сайтов, то не стоит смотреть как сделан другой похожий код. Поисковая система воспримет это как копию. А если сделаешь сам, пусть не так умно, как другие, но код работает, то это уже воспримется как уникальный. А это поисковиком расценивается с очень хорошей стороны и будет выдавать высокие позиции в поиске.

Comment: проблема шашечек и поездки

Comment: @Etki по-моему, проблема автором ответа высосана из пальца - здесь перепутаны банальный копипаст и и использование сторонних методик написания кода

Comment: > Поисковая система воспримет это как копию

@MonsI, поисковая система обычно не имеет доступа к исходникам приложений, сайтов и апплетов. Это актуально только для индексируемого контента.

Comment: @MonsI, а с каких это пор высокие позиции в поиске стали критерием качества (особенно для *кода*)?

Они могут быть мерой популярности чего-либо, но *правильные вещи* редко бывают популярны у толпы, тупо тыкающей мышью по ссылкам.